# Convert T-SQL Query to Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I want to convert my SQL Server query into Postgres.
Below is the query I have tried to convert and I am getting error in postgres

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "crosstab" LINE 2:
>   crosstab(SUM(VALUE) FOR VARIABLE IN (8,9)) p
>                          ^ QUERY:  select TIMESTAMP_S,COALESCE(8,0) AS variable_8_value,COALESCE(9,0) AS variable_9_value from
>   ARCHIEVE_EXPORT_DB_AR3 t
>                  crosstab(SUM(VALUE) FOR VARIABLE IN (8,9)) p CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function somefuncname() line 12 at EXECUTE statement
>   ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: syntax error at or near "crosstab" SQL state: 42601 Context:
>   PL/pgSQL function somefuncname() line 12 at EXECUTE statement

```sql
Declare @sql varchar(max);
Declare @sql2 varchar(max);
set @sql= STUFF((select distinct ','+ QUOTENAME(VARIABLE) from ARCHIEVE_EXPORT_DB_AR FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'');
set @sql2= STUFF((select distinct ','+ 'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(VARIABLE) + ',0)' + ' AS ' + QUOTENAME('variable_' + cast(VARIABLE as varchar) + '_value') from ARCHIEVE_EXPORT_DB_AR FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'');

set @sql='select TIMESTAMP_S,' + @sql2 + ' from ARCHIEVE_EXPORT_DB_AR t  
               PIVOT (SUM(VALUE) FOR VARIABLE IN ('+@sql+')) p';


exec(@sql);
```

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION somefuncname() RETURNS int LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
Declare 
v_sql text;
Declare 
v_sql2 text;
BEGIN
v_sql :=  STRING_AGG(Distinct(("VARIABLE"):: text), ',')   From "ARCHIEVE_EXPORT_DB_A3";
v_sql2 := STRING_AGG(Distinct('COALESCE(' || ("VARIABLE"):: text || ',0) AS variable_' || ("VARIABLE"):: text) || '_value', ',')   From "ARCHIEVE_EXPORT_DB_A3";

v_sql :='select TIMESTAMP_S,' || v_sql2 || ' from ARCHIEVE_EXPORT_DB_AR3 t  
               crosstab(SUM(VALUE) FOR VARIABLE IN (' || v_sql ||')) p';
               execute(v_sql);
END
$$;
SELECT somefuncname();
```

Comment: it appears that you have a query like `select timestamp, another_select(instead of a list columns) from table t, etc`

Answer (score 0):

It appears from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query) that you aren't using `crosstab` correctly.

`crosstab` is in a module; have you included it?  And the query within crosstab needs to be in quotes.

I suggest that you focus on getting a basic query that uses `crosstab` working first, before trying to use it in a procedure with dynamic SQL.

Comment: Will You please convert n help me with line of query set @sql='select TIMESTAMP_S,' + @sql2 + ' from ARCHIEVE_EXPORT_DB_AR t  
               PIVOT (SUM(VALUE) FOR VARIABLE IN ('+@sql+')) p';

Comment: Please Help me to convert this.